# why is there no elements getting inserted and loop goes infinite?

Tags: python, list

i am trying to get elements of list that must be string,unique and have less than 5 char but no matter what i enter as input no value is getting appended though it meets all criteria.

```
lst=[]
n=int(input("Enter number of elements:"))
while len(lst)<=n:
    print("Enter element:")
    a=input()
    if a is str and len(a)<5 and a not in lst:
        lst.append(a)
    else:
        print("Element must be string,unique and have less than 5 characters")
print(lst)
```

Answer (score 2):

`a is str` will always be `False` because `a` is an *instance* of the type `str`.  You'd use `isinstance(a, str)` to check if a was a string instance -- in this case however it's not needed because `input()` always returns a string (unless you're using a very old version of Python, in which case you can use `raw_input` instead of `input` to get the modern behavior).

```
lst = []
n = int(input("Enter number of elements:"))
while len(lst) < n:
    a = input("Enter element:\n")
    if len(a) < 5 and a not in lst:
        lst.append(a)
    else:
        print("Element must be unique and have fewer than 5 characters")

print(lst)
```

Note that you want your loop to be on `len(lst) < n` (not `<= n`) since the body of the loop will append an item *after* you've done that check.

Answer (score 0):

short answer: use **type(a) is str**.

long answer: built-in method **input** by default return string so type(a)==str always true. **a is str** always false because **is** operand compare if two variables point to the same (identical) objec.

full code:

```
lst=[]
n=int(input("Enter number of elements:"))
while len(lst)<n:
    print("Enter element:")
    a=input()
    if len(a) < 5 and a not in lst:
        lst.append(a)
    else:
        print("Element must be string,unique and have less than 5 characters")
print(lst)
```